# Ruby: How to include namespaced classes into global namespace in IRB

Tags: ruby, module, namespaces, irb

For some reason I want to use namespaced Classes/Modules as they are in global namespace in IRB.

For example I have module `MyCore` and class `MyUser` inside it. Is there any mechanism or hook for IRB to include `MyCore::MyUser` in a way I can call just `MyUser.new` without prefixing it with `MyCore`?

Comment: You can always do `MyUser = MyCore::MyUser`

Answer (score 4):

You can simply do

```
include MyCore

myUser = MyUser.new
```

Using `include` adds all the constants in the module to you current class.

```
class WhereIWantToIncludeMyCore
  include MyCore

  def initialize
    user = MyUser.new
  end
end
```

If you want to be able to do that *everywhere*, you can add it outside the scope of a `class`, which will include it to `Object`.

Comment: You can only do this assuming MyCore is a module

Comment: OP: "For example I have module `MyCore`..."

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like

```
MU = MyCore::MyUser
```

and use the alias you defined for subsequent calls.

Answer (score 0):

You can always do

```
MyUser = MyCore::MyUser
```

If you want to get all the included modules/classes:

```
MyCore.constants.each do |const|
  Object.const_set(const, MyCore.const_get(const))
end
```

Comment: Oh, iterating through all constants, great!

Answer (score 0):

i research about this problem and i found this [talking](https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/211449) & [scripts](https://github.com/dreamcat4/script/tree/master/examples/scripts)

but i thought this gem `wrap_in_module` does the best practise

[wrap_in_module](https://github.com/reachlocal/wrap_in_module)

hope it helps.