# Allow unqualified access to Ruby constants in a different module

Tags: ruby, module, namespaces, method-missing

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23520321/ruby-how-to-include-namespaced-classes-into-global-namespace-in-irb), one can get a constant into the *global* namespace with an `include` at the top level, at least in IRB. Naively, I thought I could do the same trick inside a module:

```
module Foo
  class Bar
    def frob(val)
      "frobbed #{val}"
    end
  end
end

module Baz
  include Foo
  class Qux
    def initialize(val)
      @val = val
      @bar = Bar.new
    end
    def twiddle
      @bar.frob(@val)
    end
  end
end
```

However, attempting to use this produces:

```
NameError: uninitialized constant Baz::Qux::Bar
```

I then tried overriding `Baz::const_missing` to forward to `Foo`, but it doesn't get called. `Baz::Qux::const_missing` does, but I suppose by that time the interpreter has already given up on looking in `Baz`.

How can I import `Foo` constants into `Baz` such that classes under `Baz` don't have to qualify them?

(Note that I don't just want to declare `Qux` etc. in `Foo` instead of `Baz`, for reasons of consistency between directory structure and module names.)

---

**ETA:** If I create another class `Baz::Corge`, `Baz::Qux` can refer to it without qualification. So clearly there is some sense of "peer scope". I'm aware there are several ways to make it possible for `Qux` to access `Bar`, but I'm looking for a way for *all* classes in `Baz` to access `Bar` (and all other classes in `Foo`) without qualification.

Comment: I'd say Ruby *unexpectedly?* fails at resolving of `Bar` constant, although it resides in the nearest outer scope, because it is an *inherited* constant, not a constant of the receiver - module `Baz`. I can't find source for the definitive answer, deciding if this is an intended behavior or a bug in implementation. Same issue in latest CRuby 2.2.3, also in 2.0.0 version.

Comment: Did meant, whether inherited constants can be directly accessed only in the same scope as the point of call, otherwise only fully qualified ? Not sure about this, maybe some veteran Ruby expert could make it clear ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok.. The problems is that the constant are (for some reason) not defined inside the `Quz class`, but in the upper scope, `the module Baz scope`.
If only we could somehow delegate (current word?) the constants calls in Quz to the upper (Baz) scope- We can:

Using [Module#const_missing](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Module.html#method-i-const_missing)

I'll show it twice: once for your private case, and once for a more general approach.

1) solve for private case:

```
module Foo
  class Bar
    def frob(val)
      "frobbed #{val}"
    end
  end
end

module Baz
  include Foo
  class Qux
    def self.const_missing(c)
      #const_get("#{self.to_s.split('::')[-2]}::#{c}")
      const_get("Baz::#{c}")
    end

    def initialize(val)
      @val = val
      @bar = Bar.new
    end
    def twiddle
      @bar.frob(@val)
    end
  end
end

puts Baz::Qux.new('My Value').twiddle
```

So what happens here? almost same thing- only that when the error is received- it's kinda rescued and arriving (or fall back to) the `const_missing function` to receive a new value- This apply for both Constants and Classes (apparently they are the same type).

But that mean we have to add the `self.const_missing(c)` method to every class inside module Baz- Or we can just iterate every classes in module Baz and add it (There are probably better ways to do it, but it works)

---

2) A more automated approach:

```
module Foo
  class Bar
    def frob(val)
      "frobbed #{val}"
    end
  end
end

module Baz

  class Qux
    def initialize(val)
      @val = val
      @bar = Bar.new
    end

    def twiddle
      @bar.frob(@val)
    end
  end

  def self.add_const_missing_to_classes
    module_name = self.to_s

    #note 1
    classes_arr = constants.select{|x| const_get(x).instance_of? Class} #since constants get also constants we only take classes

    #iterate classes inside module Baz and for each adding the const_missing method
    classes_arr.each do |klass| #for example klass is Qux
      const_get(klass).define_singleton_method(:const_missing) do |c|
        const_get("#{module_name}::#{c}")
      end
    end
  end

  add_const_missing_to_classes

  #we moved the include Foo to the end so that (see note1) constants doesn't return Foo's classes as well
  include Foo
end

puts Baz::Qux.new('My Value').twiddle
```

Here at the end of module Baz, after all classes were defined. we iterate them (inside the `add_const_missing_to_classes` method). to select them we use the [Module#constants](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Module.html#method-i-constants) method which returns an array of a module constants- meaning both CONSTANTS and CLASSES, so we use select method to only work on classes.

Then we iterate the found classes and add the `const_missing` class method to the classes.

Notice we moved the `include Foo` method to the end- because we wanted the `constants` method not to include constants from module Foo.

Surly there are better ways to do it. But I believe the OP's question:

> How can I import Foo constants into Baz such that classes under Baz don't have to qualify them?

Is answered

Comment: This will only work if all classes in `Baz` are defined before `add_const_missing_to_classes` is called, correct?

Comment: Yes, that's why it's called at the end.

But that was my way of adding `const_missing` to classes- you can do it however you want

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I eventually came up with. In the same file that initially declares `Baz`:

```
module Foo
  def self.included(base)
    constants.each { |c| base.const_set(c, const_get("#{self}::#{c}")) }
  end
end

module Baz
  include Foo
  #... etc.
end
```

When `Baz` includes `Foo`, it will set a corresponding constant `Baz::Whatever` for every `Foo::Whatever`, with `Foo::Whatever` as the value.

If you're worried `Foo` may already define `self.included`, you can use `alias_method` to adjust for that:

```
module Foo
  alias_method :old_included, :included if self.method_defined? :included
  def self.included(base)
    old_included(base) if method_defined? :old_included
    constants.each { |c| base.const_set(c, const_get("#{self}::#{c}")) }
  end
end
```

This approach has two limitations --

1. All the constants (including classes) in `Foo` that we care about must be defined at the time `include Foo` is evaluated -- extensions added to `Foo` later will not be captured.
2. The file that defines `Foo.included` here must be required before any file in `Baz` that uses any of those constants -- simple enough if clients are just using `require 'baz'` to pull in a `baz.rb` that in turn uses `Dir.glob` or similar to load all the other `Baz` files, but it's important not to require those files directly.

[Roko's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32980346/27358) gets around problem (1) above using `const_missing`, but it still has an analogous problem to (2), in that one has to ensure `add_const_missing_to_classes` is called after all classes in `Baz` are defined. It's a shame there's [no `const_added` hook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17407908/does-ruby-provide-a-constant-added-hook-method).

I suspect the `const_missing` approach also suffers performance-wise by depending on `const_missing` and `const_get` for every constant reference. This might be mitigated by a hybrid that caches the results, i.e. by calling `const_set` in `const_missing`, but I haven't explored that since trying to figure out scoping inside `define_singleton_method` always gives me a headache.

Answer (score -1):

As you can see from the error given: `NameError: uninitialized constant Baz::Qux::Bar`

It tries to find the `Bar class` inside `Qux class` scope- But can't find it there- why is that?

Because it's not in this scope- It's in the `Baz modlue` scope, where you used `include Foo`

So you have two options:
1) address the correct scope when calling `Bar class`,
so change this:

```
@bar = Bar.new
```

into this:

```
@bar = Baz::Bar.new
```

Like that:

```
module Baz
  include Foo
  class Qux
    def initialize(val)
      @val = val
      @bar = Baz::Bar.new
    end
    def twiddle
      @bar.frob(@val)
    end
  end
end
```

Or,

2) insert the `include Foo` into the `class Qux` itself:

```
module Baz
  class Qux
    include Foo
    def initialize(val)
      @val = val
      @bar = Bar.new
    end
    def twiddle
      @bar.frob(@val)
    end
  end
end
```

--EDIT--

As stated by joanbm this doesn't explain this behavior. You might want to take a look at [Scope of Constants in Ruby Modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2687276/scope-of-constants-in-ruby-modules). Though that post is about constants (not classes) the principles are the same.

Comment: This however does not explain `Module#include` behavior. Try in the `module Baz` scope define a constant in another way like `Bang = 123` or `const_set :Bang, 123` or define a class and unqualified access from `Qux#initialize` would be properly resolved.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware there are several ways to make it possible for `Qux` to access `Bar`, but I'm looking for a way for _all_ classes in `Baz` to access `Bar` (and all other classes in `Foo`) without qualification.

Answer (score -1):

Since Foo is included in Baz, that's where Bar is found -- it isn't found in Qux. So you can change

```
@bar = Bar.new
```

to

```
@bar = Baz::Bar.new
```

or move **include Foo** inside **class Qux**

Comment: As noted in the question, I'm aware there are several ways to make it possible for `Qux` to access `Bar`. I'm looking for ways for _all_ classes in `Baz` to access `Bar` (and all other classes in `Foo`) _without_ qualification.